# Не срабатывает on_join_member(member) event в скрипте бота для discord, когда работают другие events и commands discord.py

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py

Написал шутливого discord бота для друзей на сервере, который рассказывает анекдоты на сервере и говорит на еврейский манер.

Не срабатывает event on_join_member(member). Не очень понимаю причину проблемы.

Код:

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
from script import anekdot_script
import random
from config import settings


bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix = ('Внимание ', 'внимание '))


#bot events
@bot.event
async def on_ready(): #just give you a message that it works
    print('Таки я уже и заработал! Что клювом щёлкаешь?\nТаки моя работа и не бесплатная!')


@bot.event
async def on_member_join(member): #send a message to your message channel if a new member comes
    for channel in member.guild.channels:
        if str(channel) == 'основной':
            await channel.send_message(f"Таки и новый гость к нам пожаловал!\nШалом, {member.mention}! Таки ты готов к новый порции маленькой кошерной радости?")


#bot commands
anekdots = []
n_of_page = 1
@bot.command()
async def анекдот(ctx): #pops out a joke
    global anekdots
    global n_of_page


    anekdots, n_of_page = anekdot_script(anekdots, n_of_page)


    if anekdots:
        random.shuffle(anekdots)
        await ctx.send('Внимание, анекдот!\n')
        await ctx.send(anekdots[0].text)
        anekdots.pop(0)
    else:
        await ctx.send('Анекдоты кончились, дядя! Ну что ты так много и жадно их читаешь!\nА теперь и сами ищи себе эти анекдоты, родной!')

  
bot.run(settings['token'])
```

В консоли event on_ready() срабатывает:

```
Таки я уже и заработал! Что клювом щёлкаешь?
Таки моя работа и не бесплатная!
```

anekdot(ctx) command тоже срабатывает и выводит анекдот в дискорд чате.

Помогите, пожалуйста, найти причину проблемы и решить ее.

Answer (score 1):

не хватало пары строчек в коде - необходимо активировать Intents: https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#event-reference

Необходимые строчки:

```
intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.members = True
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix = ('Внимание ', 'внимание '), intents = intents)
```

после этого on_member_join(member) заработал